# Mongoid: has_and_belongs_to_many assignations don't trigger after_save

Tags: mongoid

I have the next code:

```
def Person
  has_and_belongs_to_many :houses

  def after_save do
    p "After save"
  end
end

def House
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
end

p = Person.create
h = House.create
p.house_ids
=> nil

p.houses << h  # it should print 'After save'
p.house_ids
=> ["540591aad9a0d13cee00003e"]
```

It should print "After save", but it doesn't trigger callback, why not?

Answer (score 0):

because `after_save` doesn't get triggered when creating object...  use `after_create` callback and it'll print correctly

Comment: I refer when I assign the house not when I create it.

Comment: if you add `p.save!` or `p.save` after `p.house_ids` it'll print "after save"